# O que é a sintaxe de objetos literais em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos, sintaxe

Alguém pode me ajudar com esta estrutura? Não sei o que é e nem como funciona.

```js
var variavel = {
    teste1: '1',
    teste2: '2',
    teste3: '3'
};
```

Comment: O que você deseja fazer? Precisa nos dar alguma parâmetro pra responder. Aparentemente está tudo ok num trecho tão curto.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela sua explicação.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como proceder. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 6):

Esta é forma de definir um objeto. Os membros do objeto está do lado esquerdo do `:`, os valores dos membros estão do lado direito.

```js
var variavel = {
    'teste1':'1',
    'teste2':'2',
    'teste3':'3'
};
console.log(variavel.teste1); //acessando o membro
console.log(variavel['teste2']); //sintaxes diferentes, mas mesmo resultado
var variavel2 = { //é mais comum fazer desta forma, ainda que funcione igual
    teste1:'1',
    teste2:'2',
    teste3:'3'
};
console.log(variavel2.teste1); //sintaxes diferentes, mas mesmo resultado
console.log(variavel2['teste2']);
```

Note que as chaves servem para definir objetos, ou seja, pares de chaves (lado esquerdo) e valores (lado direito). Se usar colchetes, aí está definindo uma sequência de dados.

```js
var variavel3 = ['1', '2', '3'];
console.log(variavel3[0]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Array.js).

Dependendo do uso só pode fazer com aspas duplas, é o caso do [JSON](http://json.org/), ainda que alguns interpretadores aceitem com a simples.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela sua explicação.

Answer (score 5):

Isso é a criação de um objeto com as propriedades `teste1`, `teste2` e `teste3`. O que tem do lado esquerdo é o identificador da propriedade, do lado direito é o valor.

É a mesma coisa que fazer o código abaixo.

```js
var variavel = {
    teste1: '1',
    teste2: '2',
    teste3: '3'
};

console.log(variavel.teste1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um objeto. A estrutura segue o padrão atributo e seu valor. Esse valor pode ser uma `String`, `boolean`, `int`, `function()`, outro objeto.
Segue um exemplo:

```
var objeto = {
    atributoUm: 'String',
    atributoDois: 10, // inteiro
    atributoTrês: true, //boolean,
    atributoQuatro: [], //array
    atributoCinco: {}, // outro objeto
    atributoSeis: function () {} //function,
    atributoSete: funcao.metodo() //método
}
```

para acessar qualquer atributo, basta chamar o seu *objeto* ponto atributo.
Exemplo:

```
objeto.atributoUm // acessa esse específico atributo deste objeto
```